# MS Word/ ODF Automation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, automation, ms-word, odf

How can I perform automation of MS Word documents (.**doc**) or ODF documents (.**odt**) in Qt 4.5? I know using the `QAxWidget`, `QAxObject`.

I have data (`QString`) and few **images** as well. I have to add them into the document. I googled but I couldn't find any commands for MS- Word/ ODF. But I want the specific commands that should be passed in `QAxObject::dynamicCall()` function to perform my operations.

For e.g in **MS Excel** we have to use something like,

```
excel.querySubObject("ActiveWorkBook");
```

which will return the object of the Active workbook of the Excel document.

**What are all the commands that are available for the generation of MS-Word or ODF (odt) documents**? I am using Windows XP. Any links, examples are welcome..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ActiveX** commands related to the MS Word can be obtained by the `VBAWD10.chm` that is being installed along with `MS - Word`.

The details of the **ActiveX help documents** available can be obtained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222101).

The toughest part is to conform those in such a way that it can accessed through the `ActiveQt` Module.

I provided a similar solution to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177268/generating-word-documents-doc-odt-through-c-qt)

Hope it helps for those who are all looking similar solutions..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq27-odfwriter.html, Qt provides functionality to create OpenDocument Format (ODF) files.