# Reading a MS Word file in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

How can I read a Word (.doc) file in Qt? I want the text to appear formatted exactly like the Word document without any loss.

Comment: Google docs and libreoffice (among many others) have been trying that for years.

Comment: it can be done using active_x object but I'm not able to figure out how.

Comment: Perhaps have a look into RTF instead. Qt has support for rich text.

Comment: If you go Windows-only, try what Marcus suggests. Cross-platform using Calligra's (http://www.calligra-suite.org) libraries might be the best bet. No third-party solution will give you exactly the same formatting as in Word though.

Comment: @cnicutar: not to mention, MS themselves try hard to get the formatting the same between versions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222101), it describes where the documentation for the ActiveX objects can be found. ActiveX Widgets can be accesed from Qt via the `QAxWidget`, queries are issued using `QAxBase::querySubObject()`.

Edit: And [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177268/generating-word-documents-doc-odt-through-c-qt). It adds some code samples to my answer.