# Where can I find the Qt operating Word document?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ms-word, word-interop

[Qt operating Word example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747787/how-to-create-docx-and-doc-file-with-qaxobject-in-qt-for-windows)

```
QAxObject   *document = documents->querySubObject("Open(const QString&, bool)", inFile1, true);
QAxObject   *selection = axObject.querySubObject("Selection");
...
document->dynamicCall("SaveAs(const QString&)", outFile);
document->dynamicCall("Close()");
```

I'm not talking about these Qt functions `querySubObject`, `dynamicCall`. I'm talking about the Word / ActiveX functions `Open`, `SaveAs`, `Close` ...

I only can glimpse a small part of these functions in some example code fragment. Where can I find the full document?

It seems ms-word functions, but considering `Open(const QString&, bool)`, there's `QString`, that dispels the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the question you linked alredy answers yours  but seeing how the accepted answer comes with no explanations at all -> Let us first go through what is missing there, then the correct solution (which the accepted answer is not).

---

What you need to know is that Qt provides conversion functions (in several files from ActiveQt). Example to illustrate `QString`:

```cpp
static inline BSTR QStringToBSTR(const QString &str)
{
    return SysAllocStringLen(reinterpret_cast<const OLECHAR*>(str.unicode()), UINT(str.length()));
}
```

What matters for `QAxBase::querySubObject` is elsewhere: the pair of functions `QVariantToVARIANT` and `VARIANTToQVariant` manage the conversion from Qt to ActiveX type and back for all the method's parameters.

---

The correct solution is to use the [most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760998/20143744) from that same question, that is:

1. run [dumpcpp.exe](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/activeqt-dumpcpp.html) on WinWord. It creates the header you need to work with Word as simply as if you were on VBA.
2. Use the classes in the `Word` namespace the same way you would do in VBA.

Between the above most voted answer and Qt documentation, it should be clear how much more simple this approach is.